# Find parametric equations of the plane $3x+4y-2z=4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea what initial point to use for planes since I'm not familiar with plotting graphs of $(x,y,z)$.

My points are

- $P_1 = (0,1,0)$
- $P_2 = (4/3, 0, 0)$
- $P_3 = (0, 0, -2)$

I calculated the positions vector which I got

- $P_1P_2 = (\frac43, -1, 0)$
- $P_1P_3 = (0, -1, -2)$

My vector equation then was **$[x,y,z] = [0, 1, 0] + [4/3, -1, 0]s + [0, -1, -2]r$**
and then I just read off this to get the parametric equations

$$x = 4s/3,y = 1-s-r,z = -2\cdot r$$

How can I determine the initial point for planes?

Comment: The initial point is arbitrary. Based on your parameterization, you chose $P_1$. You could have just as well have chosen $P_2$ or $P_3$. The parameterization is not unique.

Comment: To see that your answer is correct, leave $r,s$ unknown, and plug your parameterized point $(x,y,z)$ into the equation of the plane, testing to see if the equation is identically satisfied.

Comment: @quasi oh I get it now, thank you for clarifying my question!